# Filtrar json Array en ReactJs Debounce

Tags: reactjs, filtro, debounce

Tengo un proyecto en el cualhago peticion a una api y muestro los datos en card, ahora quiero hacer un input para filtrar el json pero hace una busqueda mal, desordenada y no entiendo porque.

aqui mi funcion:

```html
import React, { useEffect,useState}  from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import axios from 'axios';
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
 
function searchData(search){
    return function(pokemon){
      return    pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    }
}

const PokemonList=()=> {
const url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"; 
const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); 
const [data,setData]=useState([]); 
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

    const getData=async()=>{  
        await axios.get(url)
        .then(res=>{     
            setData(res.data['results']);           
        });       
    }      
        
    useEffect(()=>{    
        getData(); 
        setFilteredData(data);         
    },[data]) 
 

    return (  
    <div className="row d-flex justify-content-end">
    {filteredData?
    <>
        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-4"> 
        <div className="input-group mycustom">
                
            <input type="text" className="input form-control rounded-pill" placeholder="Search"     
            name="term" onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />

            <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <button className="btn btns btn-primary rounded-pill" type="submit"
                ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
                </button>
            </div>
               
        </div> 
        </div>

        <div className="row"> 
            {filteredData.filter(searchData(search)).map((pokemon,key)=>{
            return(
                <Card 
                key={key}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}/>
                );
            })}
        </div>
        </>
        :
        <div>Loading...</div>
        }
    </div> 
    );
}
 
export default PokemonList;
```

Comment: `search(data.map(...jsx))`esta enviando como argumento elementos JSX a la función `search`, en ese arreglo de objetos `row` no existe la propiedad `name` por ende `Cannot read properties of undefined`. Es un buen intento para tratar de implementar un filtro de búsqueda, pero ten en cuenta el detalle que mencione. Yo intentaría crear una función handle para el `search`, filtrar el estado `data` y regresar el componente nuevamente. Saludos

Comment: @g.4 Ok he modificado mi código, ya no marca error pero hace la búsqueda mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay distintas formas de implementar un **filtro de búsqueda**, estos pueden ser estáticos o dinámicos.

En el caso de los filtros dinámicos, [estos se modelan con el evento onKeyStroke](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483898/buscador-en-tiempo-real-con-fecth/484085#484085), pues se espera que cada vez que el usuario escriba una palabra en la casilla de búsqueda, el filtro muestre los resultados de forma dinámica.

---

#### Filtro Dinámico en ReactJS

En reactJS se puede usar un elemento tipo `input text`, e ir capturando cada `keyStroke` con el evento `onChange`, tal cual lo intentó el OP en el código de ejemplo:

```
<input
        placeholder='Nombre del personaje'
        name='searchInput'
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
```

#### Técnica Debounce

La técnica debounce se usa para limitar el número de invocaciones al método de búsqueda, de tal forma que, en vez de invocar al mismo en cada `keyStroke` del usuario, `debounce` configura un intervalo de tiempo entre el `input` del usuario y la invocación al método de búsqueda. Esto puede suponer **una mejora en la complejidad del tiempo** según el caso de uso.

Se puede implementar `debounce` de forma práctica con la [librería `lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce); el método recibe como argumentos una función de rebote, la cual va a ser invocada en intervalos de tiempo, el segundo argumento:

```
//funcion de rebote (método de busqueda) emitChange
//intervalo de retardo de 500 ms
let debounceFn = _.debounce(emitChange, 500);
```

Entonces, el usuario puede ingresar cierto número de caracteres en la casilla de búsqueda, pero el método de búsqueda **solo se invocará cada 500 ms**.

---

Para el método de busqueda, se pueden implementar mejoras como el manejo de ciertas cadenas de caracteres, según el caso de uso. Aquí, se muestra una implementación muy elemental con el método `filter`:

```
function emitChange(name){
    const filterResults = data.filter(item=>item.name === name);
    if(filterResults.length > 0){
      setData(filterResults);
    } else {
      setReloadFlag(true);
    }
  }
```

Nótese la adición de una bandera `reloadFlag`, para hacer uso de la reactividad de `reactJS` y recargar los datos provenientes de la `API`, en caso de no encontrar ninguna coincidencia en el filtro.

En el segundo `useEffect` se indica el uso de `setReloadFlag`  como función cleanup, para regresar la bandera a su estado inicial y poder disparar `useEffect` nuevamente en cada evento `onChange`:

```
useEffect(()=>{    
    reloadData();
    return () => setReloadFlag(false);
  },[reloadFlag]);
```

---

Finalmente, la conexión entre el método `onChange` y el método de búsqueda `reloadData` sucede a menudo,**para mejorar la complejidad en el espacio**, se hace uso del hook `useCallback`, lo que se busca es evitar que se cargen nuevas copias de la función `reloadData` por cada re-render en la memoria del explorador, además, `data` no cambiará sus contenidos a menos que se pase a la siguiente página:

```
const reloadData = useCallback(()=>{
    try{
      axios.get(url).then(res=>{     
        setData(res.data['results']);           
    }); 
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  },[]);
```

---

Demo JSX:

```js
const App=()=> {
  const url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";    
  const [data,setData]=React.useState([]); 
  const [reloadFlag, setReloadFlag] = React.useState(false);
  let debounceFn = _.debounce(emitChange, 500);

  React.useEffect(()=>{    
    try{
      axios.get(url).then(res=>{   
        setData(res.data['results']);           
    }); 
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  },[]); 
  
  const reloadData = React.useCallback(()=>{
    try{
      axios.get(url).then(res=>{     
        setData(res.data['results']);           
    }); 
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  },[]);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{    
    reloadData();
    return () => setReloadFlag(false);
  },[reloadFlag,reloadData]); 

  function handleOnChange(e){
    debounceFn(e.target.value);
  }

  function emitChange(name){
    const filterResults = data.filter(item=>item.name === name);
    if(filterResults.length > 0){
      setData(filterResults);
    } else {
      setReloadFlag(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        placeholder='Nombre del personaje'
        name='searchInput'
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      {data.map((item,index) => {
      return <p key={index}>Nombre:{item.name} - URL: {item.url}</p>
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, he replicado el codigo pero me da un error https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-leftpad-f6ibc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: En la sección add dependencies busca `lodash` y le das `Add`, luego al inicio de tu componente agregar `const _ = require("lodash")`